# Perfect number from input

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, perfect-numbers

I'm trying to  print out if a number is perfect or not by having the user enter in a number. When I enter a perfect number like 6, for example, it tells me that it is not a perfect number and can't figure out why. My final code needs to print out like 6 = 1 + 2 + 3. But I'm not that far yet.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a positive integer: ");
    int n = scanner.nextInt();

    int sum = 0;


    for(int i = 1;i<n;i++){

            if(n%2==0)
            sum += i;
    }

        if(sum==n){
            System.out.println(n + " is a positive number");
        }



        else {
            System.out.println(n + " is not a positive number");


    }
```

Comment: your print statement says "positive", not "perfect". Also, run through this code *by hand*. you type 6, we start at i=1, it's less than 6, sum += 1 means sum is now 1. i becomes 2, it's less than 6, we add 2, sum is now 3. i becomes 3, sum bcomes 6. i becomes 4, sum is now 7, and so it goes. If you don't understand why it's not saying the right thing, step one -before posting on SO- is to find out what it actually is.

Comment: Oops, it should say perfect. At any rate, I fixed the 2 to be i so I am now able to get the correct output!

Comment: then you should also select a "correct answer" from the list of answers you received, or delete your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(n%2==0)`

should be

`if(n%i==0)`

Otherwise your sum would be the sum of all numbers from `1` to `n-1` for even `n`, or `0` for odd `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would look like:

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 1;i<n;i++){
                if(n%i==0)
                sum += i;
        }

        if(sum==n){
           System.out.println(n + " is a perfect number");
           System.out.print(n+" = ");
           for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
                if(n%i==0) System.out.print((i!=1?" + ":" ") + i);                
        }
        else {
           System.out.println(n + " is not a perfect number");
        }
```

Formatting the output without using the ternary operator:

```
           System.out.println(n + " is a perfect number");
           System.out.print(n+" = ");
           for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
              if(n%i==0) {
                 if (i==1) 
                     System.out.print(i);                
                 else
                     System.out.print(" + " + i);                
              }
```

Comment: could you explain the System.out.print(i!=1?" + ":" ") part of the code?

Comment: `(i != 1 ? " + " : "")` here I am using a ternary operator is as If.
If (i != 1) // If `i` is different from 1
    {return " + "} // returns the string " + " 
else
  {Return ""} // returns null string

___ [More Info](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018)

Comment: I saw it formatted the output nicely. We just haven't learned ternary operators yet in my class but I understand how that works

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. :)

```
  public static String isPerfect(int num){
        int product = 1;
        for (int x=1; x<num; x++){
            product *= x;
            if (product == num){
                return  num + " is a perfect number";
            }
        }

       return  num + " is a not perfect number"; 
    }
```